# Number of characters in an object of class Date in R

Tags: r, as.date, nchar

I am trying to figure out the rationale for the number of characters in an R object of class `Date`, which seems to be different than I would expect based on manually counting the length of a date string. For example:

`str1 <- "2020-12-11"`
`dat1 <- as.Date(str1)`
`nchar(str1); nchar(dat1)`

Why is the character length of `str1` 10 characters (the expected result), while the length of `dat1` is only 5? Is there any way around this that results in `dat1` being 10 characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is converting to storage `integer` mode

```
as.integer(dat1)
#[1] 18607

mode(dat1)
#[1] "numeric"

nchar(dat1)
#[1] 5
```

where the number of characters is 5

while as a string, it is also counting the characters `-`